# Synology diskstation bash script: delete old files (leave only 10 newest files)

Tags: bash, synology

This works to delete files older then 14 days

```
find /path/to/share -type f -iname "*.*" -mtime +14 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

I need to modify, leave only 10 latest files, no matters how old are they

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /path/to/share -type f -iname "*.*" | sort | sed -n -e :a -e '1,10!{P;N;D;};N;ba' | xargs rm
```

PS If you not need sort, remove it.